# Creating new Class Java

Tags: java, class, object

Let say i got a class name resident.
When a new resident want to register, it will create a new object in the resident class and all related information is stored.
And the resident detail need to write into a file and store.
Can someone briefly tell me what to do and what method should i use? Thanks.

Comment: You have to create your own method. Try to write it. If you face any diffiuculty, post that.

Comment: Your question shows no results of your own first efforts to solve this problem. Please fix this by showing us the fruits of your own labors, and by explaining in detail just what it is you don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need instance variables for the things you want to track, for example firstName, lastName, address. You can set and retrieve these values by making getters and setters for every instance variable. You could also make a constructor which assings the given arguments to the instance variables when you create a new resident, since every resident would probably need at least a firstName and other data.